# Seeing 'AttributeError: __enter__ 'when expecting to see Rasa Bot responses

Tags: python-3.x, bots

I am trying to follow a post over creating and running a Rasa bot

Steps already did:
- I could get all working folders
- Got the basic data files
- Trained Nlu and Core
- launched action server and command line
- So here the expectation is User enters Input like 'Hi or hello' and then bot responds and continues the chat

Actual results: Seeing below error.

```
make cmdline
python -m rasa_core.run -d models/current/dialogue -u models/current/nlu --endpoints endpoints.yml
C:\Python3.6\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
2019-05-14 17:06:45 INFO     root  - Rasa process starting
2019-05-14 17:06:49 INFO     rasa_nlu.components  - Added 'nlp_spacy' to component cache. Key 'nlp_spacy-en'.
2019-05-14 17:07:18.101829: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2019-05-14 17:07:19 INFO     root  - Rasa Core server is up and running on http://localhost:5005
Bot loaded. Type a message and press enter (use '/stop' to exit):
Your input ->  hey
127.0.0.1 - - [2019-05-14 17:08:23] "POST /webhooks/rest/webhook?stream=true&token= HTTP/1.1" 200 190 0.254340
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python3.6\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python3.6\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python3.6\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\channels\console.py", line 114, in record_messages
    for response in bot_responses:
  File "C:\Python3.6\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\channels\console.py", line 71, in send_message_receive_stream
    with requests.post(url, json=payload, stream=True) as r:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

On preliminary search over forums, seems it is a Python code issue, as I understand it try to get bot responses using 'WITH' keyword ?

Any pointers on how can I get it sorted please ?
Thanks in advance,
Venky